# my app react-native doesn't show any ads comming from my adMob account

Tags: react-native, admob

I used the test ad id for testing my app and it seems like all is good.
but when i'm using the id for the ad i created in my admob account, my app crushed and i didn't understand the cause(s). Any ideas what is wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Add your code as a text (not image).

Comment: import { 
  AdMobBanner, 
  AdMobInterstitial
} from 'react-native-admob'


class App extends Component {
 componentWillMount() {
  AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('here_id_ad_interstitial');
  AdMobInterstitial.setTestDeviceID('EMULATOR');
                AdMobInterstitial.requestAd(AdMobInterstitial.showAd);
         AdMobInterstitial.removeEventListeners;
 } .... exple for intertitial ad

Comment: i resolved the issue and the prblem in my case was "duplicate package name", the package name for my app is already used by another developper.